# Android's tabular arrangement issue in 4 by 4 form during runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

For app having:

- *Target: API 8 or Android Froyo.*
- *The emulator:  Android GingerBread 2.0.3.*

App reads the data from the file from `/sdcard` which is supposed to be shown in **Gridview layouts**. But, in *runtime* the arrangement is **distorted** in landscape and portrait layout orientations.

> *The layout seems perfect while design time as in Image#1, but during the run time it is as seen in the Image#2.*

And here is my XML for the Layout for `landscape orientation`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutInside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bkgrnd" >
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView12"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView22"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlLeadid"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView31"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView31"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView21"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView22"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView22"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlContact"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlName"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**[EDIT]**

> ***Is there any other alternative for arrangement?***

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you try using it through the `RelativeLayout.layoutparams` and the relative layout java coding.

you can do this using any layout for example here i am using a linear layout

```
Textview hname, game,time;
    hname = new TextView(context);
            game =new TextView(context);
            time = new TextView(context);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(600, 100);

//add the settext here for ur textviews

ll.addView(hname, lp);
ll.addView(game, lp);
ll.addView(time, lp);

setcontentview(ll);
```

Comment: This is the best approach to handle this situation by far. Gingerbread had these issues at that time. All I did is was, uncluttered and redesigned the interface. And arranged the textviews as above. And Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with your `RelativeLayout`. I added 4 `LinearLayouts` in your `RelativeLayout`, all with a `weightSum` of 3 and moved your `TextViews` accordingly. I also set their `layout_weight` parameters to 1 so that they will be stretched across the screen.

I did not test this but it should work.

**EDIT** : I changed the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout seeing that all your views are below eachother

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutInside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bkgrnd" >
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView12"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/TextView22"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlLeadid"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal"
                android:typeface="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView31"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView31"
                android:text="@string/strNA"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView21"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView22"
                android:layout_below="@+id/TextView22"
                android:onClick="newActivity"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="3" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlContact"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlev2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf"
                android:text="@string/ttlName"
                android:textColor="@color/Turquoise4"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold|normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/TextView32"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Neil, It helped somewhat. 
Please see: http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/519/issuey.jpg
Can you suggest more... I think we are near to solve it, as the data has not left its vertical arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a layout something like this. I used table layout with 3 rows. The first row shows column heading and other rows shows data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ID"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contact"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1234567"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="25"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="594751"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```